# Using similar/same Javascript twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

First time posting, I wouldn't call my Javascript knowledge even rudimentary so please forgive my ignorance.

I found a snippet of code here last week (shown in first code example) and I'm trying to get a tweaked version of the same to work as well alongside.

Both are loaded into the footer together as shown below, but the one that is first works, the one that follows doesn't run

I've swapped their order in the footer and confirmed that only the first call functions correctly, I think it's just something conflicting, but I don't know what.

```js
// First function call

$(function() {
  var items = $('#v-nav>ul>li').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
      items.removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');

      //hide all content divs and show current one
      $('#v-nav>div.tab-content').hide().eq(items.index($(this))).show();

      window.location.hash = $(this).attr('tab');
    });
  });

  if (location.hash) {
    showTab(location.hash);
  } else {
    showTab("tab1");
  }

  function showTab(tab) {
    $("#v-nav ul li:[tab*=" + tab + "]").click();
  }

  // Bind the event hashchange, using jquery-hashchange-plugin
  $(window).hashchange(function() {
    showTab(location.hash.replace("#", ""));
  })

  // Trigger the event hashchange on page load, using jquery-hashchange-plugin
  $(window).hashchange();
});

// Second function call

$(function() {
  var items = $('#h-nav>ul>li').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      //remove previous class and add it to clicked tab
      items.removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');

      //hide all content divs and show current one
      $('#h-nav>div.tab-content').hide().eq(items.index($(this))).show();

      window.location.hash = $(this).attr('tab');
    });
  });

  if (location.hash) {
    showTab(location.hash);
  } else {
    showTab("tab1");
  }

  function showTab(tab) {
    $("#h-nav ul li:[tab*=" + tab + "]").click();
  }

  // Bind the event hashchange, using jquery-hashchange-plugin
  $(window).hashchange(function() {
    showTab(location.hash.replace("#", ""));
  })

  // Trigger the event hashchange on page load, using jquery-hashchange-plugin
  $(window).hashchange();
});
```

https://codepen.io/adouglas1880/pen/RzMqBV

Comment: Thanks, I had a hell of a time getting it even close to how it is in my editor. I've setup a Codepen here to help: https://codepen.io/adouglas1880/pen/RzMqBV

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what you meant but, you can see an error in the console: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #h-nav ul li:[tab*=tab1]`. You need to remove the `:` from the selector in the `showTab` function.

Comment: Thanks @MoshFeu I've tried removing the colon there (it was in the original example found on the site here) but does not seem to affect the fact that only the first function called works whilst the second is ignored.

Comment: Can you open your console (press F12, then click "Console" tab), and tell us what error do you see?

Comment: Hi @YongQuan, I get this error:

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #v-nav ul li:[tab*=tab1] `

When I remove the ":" as reccomended above I get this:

`TypeError: $(...).hashchange is not a function index.html:166:13`

Comment: Then @MoshFeu is correct, that was indeed one of the problems. It appears there's a second problem, which is `.hashchange`. I think you forgot to include the "hashchange" library in the HTML.